# performance of vmware-machine on different computers

Tags: vmware

I'm working on a filesystem improving project, and found a paper says the `cheating` on benchmark, and it gives a solution that use VMs could help others to reproduce our result.

And the question is, if I have made a specific `vmware virtual machine`, will it runs the same at different computer and platform?

For example, I have a virtual machine which is 1G RAM, 4G HD and 2G one-core CPU.

Will that runs the same at a qual-core 3G CPU and a 2.4G P4?

What if the computer have 4G RAM? Will `vmware` use some buffer mechanism to improve performance? If that's true, does it means the VM runs on a 2G RAM host will slower than on a 4G host?

Hope you can help me on that, or just told me where could I find the answer.

Comment: [ServerFault.com](http://www.serverfault.com) might be more appropriate for your question.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try there. If any answer comes out, I'll update this topic.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a VMs performance will change in line with the underlying hardware performance.

The CPU exposed to a VMware (and most other virtualization systems) virtual machine is very lightly virtualized.  All the characteristics of the CPU (i.e., its clock speed, any extended instruction sets, etc) are all visible to the guest, with very few caveats.

The CPU speed rating you give to a VM is generally only relevant under contention.  If the VM is the only one running on the machine, it will get all the CPU resources.  But if there are multiple VMs, the system (in VMware ESX at least) will use the assigned CPU resources for admission control and scheduling.  The VM will *not* be throttled if the physical CPU is faster than the virtual CPU.

For RAM, the VM will generally not use more physical RAM than the limit it was given.  But there can be indirect benefits if the host has more physical RAM (additional buffer space in the host OS may improve IO performance in some configurations).  If the physical RAM is close to equal to the virtual RAM (e.g., 1.5G of physical and 1G of virtual) then there can be significant performance impacts (as there is a non-trivial overhead memory footprint for a VM, plus the host system's resource usage).

All that said, a VM can still be a very useful tool for packaging and distributing research systems.  For example, if you run benchmarks within a VM against both old and new code paths, the results would be usefully comparable and enable others to reproduce experiments.